# Nuget package of whole Habitat solution

Tags: gulp, sitecore, nuget-package, octopack

We are following Habitat Struture which has three layers Feature,Foundation and Projects.So,all the Projects can generate separate .Nuget package using Octo pack but Can we create Nuget Package of whole solution like we publish all projects together using Gulp task from task runner explorer in visual studio?Is there any way to create Nuget package of whole Solution containing all the WebProject dlls in Feature,Foundation and project layers together?

[image]

Comment: What is the reason that you want to create a NuGet package of the complete solution artifacts/output? Is your intention to create a package to deploy to test / accept / prod servers? A good read is the following blog-post: http://blog.marcduiker.nl/2017/01/24/hands-on-with-sitecore-helix-continuous-delivery-with-octopusdeploy.html

Comment: only one iis is there to host..so wanted the package in a combined way of all the projects dlls...how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

For TDS and Helix, I create another level called `Platform` and then bundle in all the other TDS projects into my Platform project. This makes one single update package and could make one nuget package for you.

Here is an image of my Platform TDS project with the other projects included as a bundle.

[image]